# How do I stop Material-UI tooltips from hiding under adjacent ancestor elements?

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

My DOM is something like this:

```
wrapper
-element-container
--element (many)
---iconButton
```

Whenever an `element` is near the border of the `element-container`, the `tooltip` render is cut-off at the bounds of `element-container`.

How can I ensure `tooltips` always appear on top?

Here my current in-line styles:

```
element-container: {
        paddingTop: '15px',
        height: '65vh',
        overflowY: 'scroll',
      },
element: {
        border: this.props.isSelected ? '4px solid #E71E61' : 'none',
        boxSizing: 'content-box',
        width: '300px',
        transition: 'width 1.5s',
        height: '500px',
        margin: '15px',
        position: 'relative',
      },
iconButton: {
        position: 'absolute',
        marginTop: '-30px',
        marginLeft: '-30px',
        transform: this.state.isMouseOver === true ? 'scale(1,1)' : 'scale(0,0)',
        transition: 'all .2s',
      },
icon: {
        height: '40px',
        width: '40px'
      },
```

I've tried:

- setting the `zIndex` of both the `tooltip` (via the `tooltipStyle` prop of `IconButton`
- changing the `position` of each element to different values (since [this issue](https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/issues/210) indicates `position` affects `zIndex`)
- overwrting the entire `tooltipStyle` with the default `style` found in the [MUI source code](https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/blob/master/src/internal/Tooltip.js)

ETA: Here's a screen shot of the issue I'm describing. My screenshot app doesn't capture the pointer, so I've drawn one to indicate that the mouse is over the grey circle button.

[image: description of tooltip issue]

The cut-off tooltip is the dark box with the letters 'ing' visible. While this pic shows cut-off on the left side of the container, all sides behave the same.

Comment: will you provide some visuals please ?

Comment: great idea--added one to the OP. thanks Mehdi.

Comment: i've since switched to react-mdl, so haven't tried this solution w/ material-ui, but in similar cases, i've found that the problem is some ancestor container in the component hierarchy `overflow` set to `hidden`. In `react-mdl`, for example, the `Card` component had a default css property of `overflow: hidden`, which was affecting menus, tooltips, etc.